# I'm sampling a population, looking for a small proportion of individuals

Tags: self-study

I want to find some particular individuals in a population, ones with a special genetic makeup for instance. I estimate the population to be 10000 and I'm hoping to find one of 45 individuals. I sample 2000 but still haven't found any. Assuming my sampling is random, how do I put a figure on the likelihood of that happening?

Comment: **Hint** What's the chance of not finding one of those individuals in a sample of 1?  How about the chance of not finding one of them in another sample of 1 from the remaining 9999?  Now put the two answers together: what was the chance of not finding any individual in the two samples?  Iterate...

Answer (score 0):

*I am answering this very old question just so it has an answer.*

### Formula and numeric answer

$$ \Pi_{i=0}^{1999} \frac{9955-i}{10000-i} \approx .00004 $$

### Detailed Explanation

Let's think about what it would look like for you to take this random sample and not get any of the people you are interested in.

For brevity, let's call the **s**ubpopulation of 45 people you are interested in $S$.
When you choose your first person, you fail to get somebody from $S$. There are $10000$ people in total and $9955$ are not in $S$, so the probability of doing this is $9955/10000$.

Now you make the next random choice, but now there are only 9999 people overall, you still have all $45$ of the people in $S$ - and the other $9954$ are people you are not interested in . You make your choice, and once again get somebody you are not interested in - there are $9954/9999$ ways to do this. (You have found the probability of failing to select someone from $S$ *given* that you have had one previous attempt which was a failure).

...

Repeating this, eventually you get to the last, 2000th selection.
By this point there are $8001$ people in the whole population, and still $45$ in $S$ as you have failed to get any so far. The probability of failing to get any of $S$ on this final selection is $7956/8001$.

Finally, you want the probability of **all** of these things happening - i.e. failing on each selection.
So you would multiply each of the probabilities (look up conditional probability). We can write this as the formula at the top.

### Code

For reference, here is the Python code I used to calculate the product.

```
product=1
numerator=9955
denom = 10000
for i in range(0,2000):
    product*=(numerator)/denom
    numerator-=1
    denom-=1
print(product)
```